# If you can verify that a JKS keystore has not been changed is there any benefit from passwording it?

Tags: java, android, security

For example, say the keystore is being tracked in Git, so we can be certain it has not been tampered with. Would having a password on the keystore add anything security-wise? Is omitting the keystore password in any way a security risk in this situation?

NB: In case it matters, the keystore is being used to store public/private key certificates for signing Android apps, and the private keys inside the keystore are encrypted with strong passphrases.

Comment: The keystore encryption was made specifically with security in mind (at least I hope so :) ) while for Git's hash generation and hash checking this may not have been the primary goal

Comment: +1 first comment. Also this is not programming question, and thus off topic. If you are relying on third party tools (Git, etc.), you are at risk when they get broken and/or compromised. The JKS integrity check is built-in and self contained. You may as well keep the SHA1 hash of the file on post-it on your desk, but what happens when you lose the post-it? :)

Comment: Being tracked in git was just a practical example of why I might have a few hundred backups of the keystore's SHA-1 hash :)

Comment: Also if SHA1 is compromised, then keytool will be as well - it uses SHA1 to create the signature, according to http://code.google.com/p/zip-signer/source/browse/zipsigner-lib-optional/trunk/src/main/java/kellinwood/security/zipsigner/optional/JKS.java?spec=svn449&r=449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a lot of Googling, reading and experimenting and I believe the answer to my question is "no".

The keystore password is only used as part of signature generation: it protects against tampering, but does not prevent inspection. If you can guarantee the file has not changed one bit, you can guarantee is has not been tampered with, and so adding a keystore password in this scenario does not provide any additional security.

Sources:

The [Java keytool documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/keytool.html) only refers to the keystore password as verifying integrity, never encryption - but doesn't explicitly say it only protects against tampering.

The [Bouncy Castle specifications (section 5.4)](http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) states that when operating "in the same fashion" as JKS, "The keystore is resistent to tampering but not inspection." - which strongly suggests this is true for JKS

Most concrete but least official is [the reverse-engineered implementation of JKS](http://code.google.com/p/zip-signer/source/browse/zipsigner-lib-optional/trunk/src/main/java/kellinwood/security/zipsigner/optional/JKS.java?spec=svn449&r=449#133) which also backs up the claim that the keystore is not encrypted with the keystore password.

Experiments:

My first experiment was to change the password on a keystore and see how much changed in a hex editor, and it looked like only the last few bytes of the file changed.

Second experiment: Create a keystore with a password, generate and store a key with a different password. Retrieve the key from the keystore both with the correct keystore password, and a blank password. You get bit-for-bit identical results.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, private keys should always be stored as safe as possible.

As taken from Sun/Oracle official documentation

`There is a built-in default keystore implementation type known as "jks" that is provided by Sun Microsystems. It implements the keystore as a file, utilizing a proprietary keystore type (format). It protects each private key with its own individual password, and also protects the integrity of the entire keystore with a (possibly different) password...`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#KeystoreImplementation

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I was under the impression that in a JKS keystore, passwording the keystore itself does not encrypt the contents?